# Why MySQL works different from SQLServer, allowing multiple columns using GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

In this scheme http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f86a/1, build on MySQL, I did a query getting all records grouped by register number. In my opinion, it's would be invalid, because I brought a not aggregated column grouped by register number.

code below:

```
create table client 
  (id int not null auto_increment, 
   city varchar(50), 
   register int,
   primary key(id));

insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('MG', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('ES', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 222);
insert into client (city, register) values ('MG', 222);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 333);
```

The query `select * from client group by register` returns:

```
id  city    register
1   SP      111
5   SP      222
7   SP      333
```

In this other scheme http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b1ba1/1, build on SQLServer, the error 'Column 'client.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' is returned, according what I said.

code below:

```
create table client 
  (id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
   city varchar(50), 
   register int);

insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('MG', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('ES', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 111);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 222);
insert into client (city, register) values ('MG', 222);
insert into client (city, register) values ('SP', 333);
```

the same previous query `select * from client group by register` returns:

> Column 'client.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why MySQL is more permissive? Could not this bring unwanted results?

Comment: it's not a good idea to put question materials on different site

Comment: @FLICKER, thanks... I've corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why MySQL is more permissive? Could not this bring unwanted results?

It will undeniably return *indeterminate* results for the unaggregated column that's not part of the GROUP BY clause. More jaded database developers, myself included, have always considered this *broken as designed (BAD)* rather than *permissive*.

MySQL's default behavior changed a couple of years ago in version 5.7.5. Your query on sqlfiddle.com uses version 5.6. Version 5.7.5 moves MySQL closer to standard SQL with respect to GROUP BY.